# Inexpensive or free software to just use to draw chemical equations and structures

Tags: software-recommendation, free

I am a chemistry professor who is finishing semester sequestered because of COVID-19.  I bought a Huion 1060+ with the intent of using it write equations/formulas for my students in our online classes.  I am not drawing major artwork - just an occasional simple molecular structure.

Comment: Maybe https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place for this question?

Comment: Thanks Zach.  As this sort of technology is not my area of expertise, I had no idea 2 days ago that it existed, so you just helped me with my next step.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean *handwrite* formulas (as you would on a black/whiteboard), or *typeset* them (as you would read them on a book)?

Answer (score 13):

I know there's an open-source extension to LATEX specifically for chemical formulae - I *think* it's called chemfig - here's what I just found on quick lookup:

[Overleaf - Chemfig](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/chemistry_formulae)

Also, for simple diagrammatic stuff, if you don't feel you need a *chemistry formula **specific** tool*, and general graphics / vector drawing works for you, then bear in mind that [**Inkscape**](https://inkscape.org/) is free and open source.

Answer (score 7):

Chemsketch is free for academic use:
https://www.acdlabs.com/resources/freeware/chemsketch/

Answer (score 6):

If you only want to draw them by hand, as you were on a blackboard you can use any simple paint program, there are several free ones.

- *MyPaint https://github.com/mypaint/mypaint/releases
- FireAlpaca https://firealpaca.com/
- MediBang https://medibangpaint.com/
- Krita https://krita.org/
- Gimp https://www.gimp.org/
- PaintNet https://www.getpaint.net/

Take a look at them. They are free so just test them.

1. Define a similar-sized canvas on a couple of programs, let's say 1920x1080 or smaller.
2. See which one is more intuitive for you, and draws more fluidly with your hardware.

You can save your boards as an archive or simply delete the artboard.

*One detail about MyPaint. It has an "infinite canvas" this is, If you need more space you can simply drag it a little or zoom out and you have now a bigger canvas. It is useful but beware not to create a monster that will paralyze your computer. Zoom out, but remember to zoom in again.

Answer (score 4):

Word and Powerpoint or their free rivals such as LibreOffice or OpenOffice have editors for quite rich formulas. They are very easy, but typographic control in LaTeX style is zero.

Structure diagrams need a drawing program. Office products have something quite clunky but easy to learn. Inkscape is the complex but capable one freebie.

Check this molecule structure editor http://molview.org It exports PNG images and knows nothing if the drawn molecule is possible or not. Read the license carefully to see what you give and promise if you use it.

Comment: I second LibreOffice Math. It's not great, but it does have a GUI and it's easy to learn.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I use LibreOffice Math *extensively* and I find it to be near perfect. You say that it isn't great, which implies some sort of shortcoming. Can you share what you have in mind?

Comment: @john01dav It's not as powerful as TeX.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 What useful thing, specifically, can TeX's equation system do that Libreoffice Math can't?

Comment: @john01dav Matrices.

Comment: @john01dav LaTeX is a typesetting language for arbitary texts. Also drawings are possible. Equation editors are not especially flexible for making full pages of stuff. A single formula can be acceptable but one cannot specify exact placements, everything must be accepted as the equation editor decides. But is it useful? A genius can write the final layout with LaTeX at the same time when he creates the content i.e. does the actual work. I guess I'm not the only who prefer something simpler when I must create the content, too.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 That's just not true though: `left [
matrix {
a # c ##
b # d
}
right ] 
left[ 
matrix { 
x ## y
}
right ] = 
left [ matrix { 
 ax+cy ##
 bx+dy
} right ]
`

Comment: @user287001 That's a good point about arbitrary diagrams. Libreoffice's formula editor isn't great for that (although I've always found the GUI tools in Libreoffice Draw to be acceptable, but not great — it may be worth learnign Latex for that). Wrt whole pages though, you absolutely can do that in Libreoffice easily, and I have, many times. You just use a Libreoffice Writer document with equation objects. Also, for the most part, you can specify exact placements. It's probably not quite as powerful as something designed for arbitrary diagrams, but it's pretty darn close in my experience.

Comment: An equation editor + a program for writing and drawing, together they are the simple thing that fits between my ears. Defining full pages as sentences of a description language needs a person who has less bone between the ears. I see we agree.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Ubuntu there are a number of free molecule and chemical compoud graphing solutions:  Avogadro, Bist, Bkchem, etc.  Most output to png, svg, etc.   Just get on synaptic and search "chem"

Answer (score 1):

There are also on-line editors, for instance [cactus](https://cactus.nci.nih.gov/) has both gif and vmrl structure creators.